# Javascript push more data

Tags: javascript

How can I push or add more data to `strData` dynamically.

```
var strData = {
  'attributes[]': 'data'
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: strData?  It's an object not a string.

Answer (score 5):

Just assign a value to a property

```
strData.someName = someValue;
```

If you mean "to `'attributes[]'`", then you need to make it an array to start with.

```
var strData = {
  'attributes': ['data']
};

strData.attributes.push(someValue);
```

Comment: Then refer to the first part of Quentin's answer. strData.someName = someValue;

Comment: And if I want strData.someName to be an array of values??

Comment: Then make `someValue` be an array.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to add manual keys or indexes to strData.someValue? And how to define that?

Comment: Any JS object can be the value of a property of another object. If you want named keys, use a simple object. If you want an array, use an array. If you want a Date, use a Date. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to add another "'attributes2[]': 'data'" dynamically to the strData. Could you give me a sample code to do that?

Comment: `strData['attributes2[]'] = 'data';`

Answer (score 1):

```
var strData = {
    'attributes' = ['data','more data','some more data']
};
```